# How to extract nested json arrays from Redshift field

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I was able to use json_parse to extract the data from JSON arrays. It is working fine for 1 or 2 levels. However, there are certain fields has dynamic multi level arrays with 1 to many rows combination.

What is the best way to extract the data using queries instead of using pyhton scripts.

Need output with 1 to many rows by ID.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.